# How to show AlertDialog with edittext onTextChanged

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, textwatcher

I have an `activity` with several `EditTexts`. If the user clicks '`Cancel`' button and nothing has changed in these `EditTexts` then the app should go to the previous activity but if something has changed in these `EditTexts` then I want the user to see the `AlertDialog`:

```
Save changes you made?

NO       YES
```

I have set up a `TextWatcher` for these `EditTexts` like:

```
  //let's set up a textwatcher so if the state of any of the edittexts has changed.
    //if it has changed and user clicks 'CANCEL', we'll ask first, '
    //You've made changes here. Sure you want to cancel?'
    TextWatcher edittw = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Toast.makeText(EditContact.this, "change detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

    categoryname.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
    namename.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
    phonename.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
    addressname.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
    commentname.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
```

And my `AlertDialog` for the `Cancel` button - which is appearing regardless of whether any `EditTexts` have changed or not, but I just want it to appear only if changes are made in the `EditTexts`, otherwise there should be no `AlerDialog` and current activity should go back to previous activity - goes like:

```
private void cancelButton() {

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //add a dialogue box
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                builder.setMessage("Save changes you made?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

            }

        });


    }

    //Are you sure you want to cancel? dialogue
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Yes button clicked

                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditContact.this);
                    // Showing progress dialog for the review being saved
                    pDialog.setMessage("Saving...");
                    pDialog.show();

                    //post the review_id in the current activity to EditContact.php and

                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EditContact_URL,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    //hide the dialogue saying 'Saving...' when page is saved
                                    pDialog.dismiss();

                                    Toast.makeText(EditContact.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(EditContact.this, "problem here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                            }) {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            //we are posting review_id into our EditContact.php file,
                            //the second value, review_id,
                            // is the value we get from Android.
                            // When we see this in our php,  $_POST["review_id"],
                            //put in the value from Android
                            params.put("review_id", review_id);
                            return params;
                        }


                    };


                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

                    //when cancelled, back to the PopulistoListView class

                    Intent j = new Intent(EditContact.this,PopulistoListView.class);

                    startActivity(j);


                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

                    //close the activity
                    finish();
            }
        }
    };
```

I have searched the internet for tutorials or posts with phrases like 'TextWatcher' and 'AlertDialog' but I've not found something that will help me acheive what I am trying to do.

Comment: then you should show the alertdialogue in your `afterTextChanged()` method, is not it?

Comment: But if I put `cancelButton();` in `afterTextChanged()` the dialog will show as soon as the user types in the editText.

Comment: no you will create the `alertDialogue` inside the `afterTextchanged()` method and listen to them (yes/no) inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `boolean` variable to track `textChange`

```
boolean isDirty;
TextWatcher edittw = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Toast.makeText(EditContact.this, "change detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isDirty = true;

        }
    };

    categoryname.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
    namename.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
    phonename.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
    addressname.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
    commentname.addTextChangedListener(edittw);
```

And change you cancel button click event to this

```
private void cancelButton() {

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(isDirty) {
                    //add a dialogue box
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                    builder.setMessage("Save changes you made?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
                }
                else {
                    // this will finish the current activity and the last activity will be popped from the stack. 
                    finish();
                }

            }

        });


    }
```

Comment: @downvoter, do you have a little courtesy to explain your downvote ?

Comment: Wasn't me anyway, thanks - I tried a solution like above but couldn't get it working, will try yours shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Try add alertDialog like below, you can put dialog inside onAfterChange method:

```js
TextWatcher edittw = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                Toast.makeText(EditContact.this, "change detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
                } else {
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                }
                builder.setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //You want yes
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //You want no
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply use boolean variable like so

- declare check variable in class properties

  boolean check ;
- set the value of this variable in `onTextChange()` to `true` in the `TextWatcher`
- change `cancelButton()` to this

  ```
  private void cancelButton() {

  cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          if(changed){

          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());

          builder.setMessage("Save changes you made?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                  .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

          }else {

              Log.v(TAG,"nothing changed ");

          }
      }
  });

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
//onCancel Clicked
if(somethingChanged)//compare old values with new values
   showDialog();
else
   onBackPressed();
```

Comment: updated answer as i missed that you want to show dialog on cancel click

Answer (score 0):

In cancel button onClick method just try this :-

```
 @Override
 onClick(View v) {

   if(!(categoryname.getText().toString().isEmpty() && namename.getText().toString().isEmpty() && phonename.getText().toString().isEmpty() && addressname.getText().toString().isEmpty() && commentname.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {

   // show your dialog
   }
   else {

     // normal cancel

   }
```

Just `check the text` in all the `edittexts` , if any one of them is not empty , show the dialog.. !!

> No need to add `textChangeListener` for the above problem !!

Comment: all that has to happen in an editText is a change, they don't necessarily all need to be empty.

Comment: if any of the edittext is not empty...only then you need to show the dialog ryt?? @CHarris ?